# Looping over a buffer received by a client program

Tags: c, string, parsing, tokenize, c-strings

newbie on C programming here searching for a little help! I have a buffer containing some data provided by a client program lets say something like this:

*pcity:Amsterdam gcity*

my problem is that inside the server I would like to iterate over this loop and "pop" the commands and the arguments I already have sent an answer to the client. In this example, lets say, after I handle the pcityAmsterdam part I would like the buffer to become gcity.

This is my code so far:

```
while(sizeof(incbuf) > 0) 
    {
        if(incbuf[0] == 103) //get request
        {   
            puts("get req");
            memmove(incbuf, incbuf+1, strlen(incbuf));
            //puts(incbuf);
            key = strtok(incbuf, ":");
            //printf("%s\n",key);
            res = get(key);

            printf("%s\n",&res);
            if(res != NULL) //we got a match
            {
                puts("match");
                if(servbuf[0] == '\0')
                    servbuf[0] = 102;
                else
                    servbuf[strlen(servbuf)] = 102;
                strcat(servbuf, res);
                send(new_socket,servbuf,1024, 0);

            }
            else //not found
            {
                puts("not a match");
                if(servbuf[0] == '\0')
                    servbuf[0] = 110;
                else
                    servbuf[strlen(servbuf)] = 110;
                strcat(servbuf, &res);
                printf("BEFORE THE NOT FOUND: %s\n", servbuf);
                send(new_socket,servbuf,1024, 0);
            }
            memmove(incbuf, incbuf+strlen(key), strlen(incbuf));
            printf("%s\n", incbuf);
        }
        else if(incbuf[0] == 112) //put request
        {

            puts("put req");
            memmove(incbuf, incbuf+1, strlen(incbuf));


            char* keytoken  = strtok(incbuf, ":"); //get rid of the type
            printf("token: %s\n",keytoken );

            char* key       = malloc((strlen(keytoken)));
            char* value     = malloc((strlen(incbuf))); //Amsterdam--> key :city

            strcpy(key, keytoken);
            printf("key: %s\n",key );

            char* valuetoken = strtok(NULL, ": ");
            strcpy(value, valuetoken);
            printf("value: %s\n",value );
            put(key, value);

            memmove(incbuf, incbuf+strlen(key)+strlen(value)+1, strlen(incbuf));
            printf("AFTER MEMMOVE THIS IS THE BUF: %s\n", incbuf);

        }
```

I know at this point that strtok messing with my incbuf array but I need it in order to tokenize the array. Probably a design problem here?

Any suggestions?

Comment: Is there some kind of separator between "commands"? With the example you show it looks like there's a space between the `pcity` command (with its argument) and the `gcity` command. Is this space mandatory according to your protocol specification?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude it should be a null terminator there but I cannot tokenize with strtok when having a null terminator there, so I have put a space for my convenience.

Comment: Then just loop over the buffer (you do know its actual length?) and copy characters into another buffer. When you hit the command terminator (`0`) you have a full command that you can process. Handle the current command, then continue the loop over the receive buffer.

Comment: What is `while(sizeof(incbuf) > 0)` supposed to do?  `sizeof(incbuf)` is a constant that will never change.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to do it with a workaround. (copying the incbuf to a temporary buffer did the trick, thanks for pointing out. )

```
while(strlen(incbuf) > 0) 
    {

        for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(incbuf); ++i)
            tmpbuf[i] = incbuf[i];


        if(incbuf[0] == 103) //get request
        {   
            memmove(tmpbuf, tmpbuf+1, strlen(tmpbuf));
            key = strtok(tmpbuf, " ");
            res = get(key);

            //printf("%p\n",(void*) &res);
            if(res != NULL) //we got a match
            {

                if(servbuf[0] == '\0')
                    servbuf[0] = 102;
                else
                    servbuf[strlen(servbuf)] = 102;
                strcat(servbuf, res);
                send(new_socket,servbuf,1024, 0);

            memset(servbuf, '\0', sizeof(servbuf));
            memmove(incbuf, incbuf+strlen(key), strlen(incbuf) - strlen(key));


            }
            else //not found
            {
                if(servbuf[0] == '\0')
                    servbuf[0] = 110;
                else
                    servbuf[strlen(servbuf)] = 110;
                strcat(servbuf, &res);
                send(new_socket,servbuf,1024, 0);
            }
            memset(servbuf, '\0', sizeof(servbuf));
            memmove(incbuf, incbuf+strlen(key)+2, strlen(incbuf) - strlen(key) +1);
            //memmove(incbuf, incbuf+strlen(key), strlen(incbuf));
        }
        else if(incbuf[0] == 112) //put request
        {

            memmove(tmpbuf, tmpbuf+1, strlen(tmpbuf));
            char* keytoken  = strtok(tmpbuf, ":"); //get rid of the type
            char* key       = malloc((strlen(keytoken)));
            char* value     = malloc((strlen(tmpbuf))); //Amsterdam--> key :city

            strcpy(key, keytoken);
            char* valuetoken = strtok(NULL, ": ");
            strcpy(value, valuetoken);
            put(key, value);

            memset(servbuf, '\0', sizeof(servbuf));
            memmove(incbuf, incbuf+strlen(key)+2 + strlen(value)+1, strlen(incbuf) - strlen(key) -strlen(value) +1);

        }
        else //immediate disconnection of the server in case of invalid requests
        {
            printf("ERROR\n");
            close(new_socket);
            exit(1);
        }
    }
```